# android edit text change background in focus

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have used edit text in my app and I want to change the background when the  edit text is focused. I wrote some code but I am facing a problem. I need twice click in edit text to show  keyboard.

This is my code:

```
  private View.OnFocusChangeListener myEditTextFocus =  new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasfocus) {
        if (hasfocus) {
            ((EditText) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_input_background_focus);

            ((EditText) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4d4d4d"));

        }
        else {
            ((EditText) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_input_background_not_focus);

        }
    };
};
```

The problem is this code because I commented it and everything was perfect.What is wrong with my code? Or, Is there any other solution?

Comment: Have you tried <selector> in drawable?

Comment: no i don't know how to use it .i want to chenage textcolor and background in focus @ChiragSavsani Savsani

Answer (score 21):

//Follow this code

Put these 3 drawable files in res/drawable folder

**simple_edittext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#FB9820" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

**focus_edittext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#58ACFA" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#FB9820" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

**selector_edittext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focus_edittext"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/simple_edittext" />
</selector>
```

And use these drawbles like this :

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_edittext"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_edittext"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use the state:

```
android:state_window_focused="true"
```

on the bg.xml drawable file:

```
    <item android:state_window_focused="true" android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <corners
                android:radius="55dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorGrey2" />
            <corners
                android:radius="55dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>


</selector>
```

and edit text will looks like:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_margin="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily use `android:textColorHighlight="@color/your_color_name"` attribute of `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText`